# Add choice to Dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint, dropdown

I have two lists in sharepoint 2010

Example:

**Parent List contains below choices**

- Fruits
- Vegetables
- Drinks

**Child List contains below choices**

- Tomato
- Potato
- Brinjal
- Apple
- Orange
- Grapes
- Pepsi
- Coke
- Fanta

If i select fruits in the parent list only fruits should display in the child dropdown list.

I have already tried with SPservices, but it does not worked out.

Comment: Assuming these are lookup fields from a list, and you want cascading dropdowns in new form or edit form, you have two choices. One is to make it in InfoPath (there are tutorials online), the other is to use javascript to have a function onchange of the parent list to populate the child.

Comment: Please share your code that you have written using SPServices. Because I have been SPServices for cascading drop-down and it works perfectly for me.